# Error when using an OR within an IF statement with 'contains' method

Tags: apex, trigger

Getting an error with the following code snippet of "Save error: expecting a right parentheses, found 'OR'" .  It works if I use only the first contains, but then errors when I add the OR and second contains.

```
        if(c.Billing_Contact__c.contains('Billing') OR (c.Billing_Contact__c.contains('SO')){
```

Is it not possible to use the OR within the IF statement?  I saw other examples where it worked, but not when I was using the contains method within.  Something simple that I'm missing here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the operator || and not OR. See here the various Apex [operators](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/langCon_apex_expressions_operators_understanding.htm)

Comment: Wow... beautiful!  I did that earlier but was still getting the same error - must not have refreshed it :|

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Try like this replace OR with || operator.

if(c.Billing_Contact__c.contains('Billing') || c.Billing_Contact__c.contains('SO')){